# switchClass in jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website where html tag has a background image using css. I have created an a tag and when you click on it html tag background image should change through CSS. I am using switchClass but it doesn work. Find below my code:

1. line:

```html
<html class="background1">
```

2. with  link that triggers jQuery:

```html
<div id=photoNum>
    <a class="photoLink" href="#">1</a>
  </div>
```

3. CSS:

```css
.background1 {
  background: url(Photos/Main.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

.background2 {
  background: url(Photos/Main2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

.background3 {
  background: url(Photos/Main3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

.background4 {
  background: url(Photos/Main4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

4. jquery script:

```js
<script>
    $('.photoLink').on('click', function() {
      $('html').switchClass('background1', 'background3');
    });
  </script>
```

Tried with toggleClass, to check if it was a matter of semantics, but toggleClass works, so can't find why script is not working. I am referencing a jquery library on top:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `switchClass` is from `jquery.ui` are you including that library?

Comment: hey @Victory, thank you so much, it solved the issue! I have a follow up question, as I am learning jQuery: how to know to which library a jQuery method belongs to? Can't find this type of info in the jQuery API page: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/ Thanks,

Comment: Its hard to say what library a function is in just by name, google and having http://api.jquery.com/ open is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `class` attribute on the `html` tag.  Put it on the `body` tag instead.

```html
<body class="background1">
```

and

```
...
$('body').switchClass('background1', 'background3');
...
```

Comment: thanks! That is another option indeed. However, @victory solution about the library fixed the issue, so it seems I can add a class in the html. At least it works for me!